# changing the text area value for selected checkboxes when click on applyAll button using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I need to display a block comments of selected check boxes with respective comments fields only(i.e if we select 1,3 check boxes and typing a comments and when we clicking on apply all button it should replace the comments fields of 1,3 after if we select 2,4 again when we change the text of comments and clicks on apply all button it should replace the comments fields of 2,4 only it shouldn't replace the 1,2,3,4 with new comments) can any one help me?

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', []);
app.controller("profileController", function($scope) {

 $scope.personalDetails = [
            {
               'fname':'Muhammed',
                'lname':'Shanid',
                'email':'shanid@shanid.com',
                'check' : 'Y',
                'checkxDrpn' : [
                  { key: 'Y',selectVal: "Yes"},
                  { key: 'N',selectVal: "No"}
                ],
                'indivalCmts' : ''
            },
            {
                'fname':'John',
                'lname':'Abraham',
                'email':'john@gmail.com',
                'check' : 'N',
                'checkxDrpn' : [
                  { key: 'Y',selectVal: "Yes"},
                  { key: 'N',selectVal: "No"}
                ],
                'indivalCmts' : ''
            },
            {
                'fname':'raj',
                'lname':'komali',
                'email':'raj@gmail.com',
                'check' : 'N',
                 'checkxDrpn' : [
                  { key: 'Y',selectVal: "Yes"},
                  { key: 'N',selectVal: "No"}
                ],
                'indivalCmts' : ''
            },
            {
                'fname':'Roy',
                'lname':'Mathew',
                'email':'roy@roy.com',
                'check' : 'N',
                 'checkxDrpn' : [
                  { key: 'Y',selectVal: "Yes"},
                  { key: 'N',selectVal: "No"}
                ],
                'indivalCmts' : ''
            }];
            
 $scope.applyCmtsAll = function(personBlckCmts) {
  angular.forEach($scope.personalDetails, function(value) {
   if (value.selected == true) {
    console.log("value " + value);
    value.selectedDpn.selectVal = "Yes";
    value.indivalCmts = personBlckCmts;
    //$scope.indivalCmts==personBlckCmts;
    return;
   }
  });
 }
   
});
```

```css
.selected {
     text-decoration: line-through;

  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="demo" ng-controller="profileController">
<div class="">
    <textarea ng-model="personBlckCmts"></textarea>
    <button  class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="applyCmtsAll(personBlckCmts)">Apply All</button>
 </div>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th></th>
     <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()" /></th>
     <th>Firstname</th>
     <th>Lastname</th>
     <th>Email</th>
     <th>Yes/No</th>
     <th>Comment</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>                         
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="personalDetail in personalDetails" ng-class="{'selected':personalDetail.selected}">
        <td>{{$index}}</td>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" ng-click="setClickedRow($index)" ng-model="personalDetail.selected" ng-disabled="personalDetail.selected"/>
  </td>
   <td>
     <span>{{personalDetail.fname}}</span>
  </td>   
  <td>
     <span>{{personalDetail.lname}}</span>
  </td> 
   <td>
     <span>{{personalDetail.email}}</span>
  </td> 
           
          <td>
             <select  ng-init="personalDetail.selectedDpn= personalDetail.checkxDrpn[1]" ng-options="value as value.selectVal for value in personalDetail.checkxDrpn track by value.key"
        ng-model="personalDetail.selectedDpn" ></select>
       </td>
    <td>
  <textarea ng-model="indivalCmts" ng-disabled="personalDetail.selected">
    
  </textarea>
    </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your source code here. May be it will help to solve your issue.

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', []);
app.controller("profileController", function($scope) {

 $scope.personalDetails = [
            {
               'fname':'Muhammed',
                'lname':'Shanid',
                'email':'shanid@shanid.com',
                'check' : 'Y',
                'checkxDrpn' : [
                  { key: 'Y',selectVal: "Yes"},
                  { key: 'N',selectVal: "No"}
                ],
                'indivalCmts' : ''
            },
            {
                'fname':'John',
                'lname':'Abraham',
                'email':'john@gmail.com',
                'check' : 'N',
                'checkxDrpn' : [
                  { key: 'Y',selectVal: "Yes"},
                  { key: 'N',selectVal: "No"}
                ],
                'indivalCmts' : ''
            },
            {
                'fname':'raj',
                'lname':'komali',
                'email':'raj@gmail.com',
                'check' : 'N',
                 'checkxDrpn' : [
                  { key: 'Y',selectVal: "Yes"},
                  { key: 'N',selectVal: "No"}
                ],
                'indivalCmts' : ''
            },
            {
                'fname':'Roy',
                'lname':'Mathew',
                'email':'roy@roy.com',
                'check' : 'N',
                 'checkxDrpn' : [
                  { key: 'Y',selectVal: "Yes"},
                  { key: 'N',selectVal: "No"}
                ],
                'indivalCmts' : ''
            }];
            
 $scope.applyCmtsAll = function(personBlckCmts) {
  angular.forEach($scope.personalDetails, function(value) {
   if (value.selected == true) {
    
    value.selectedDpn.selectVal = "Yes";
    value.indivalCmts = personBlckCmts; 
    value.selected = false;
   }
  });
  $scope.personBlckCmts='';
 }
   
});
```

```css
.selected {
     text-decoration: line-through;

  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="demo" ng-controller="profileController">
<div class="">
    <textarea ng-model="personBlckCmts"></textarea>
    <button  class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="applyCmtsAll(personBlckCmts)">Apply All</button>
 </div>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th></th>
     <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()" /></th>
     <th>Firstname</th>
     <th>Lastname</th>
     <th>Email</th>
     <th>Yes/No</th>
     <th>Comment</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>                         
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="personalDetail in personalDetails" ng-class="{'selected':personalDetail.selected}">
        <td>{{$index}}</td>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" ng-click="setClickedRow($index)" ng-model="personalDetail.selected" ng-disabled="personalDetail.selected"/>
  </td>
   <td>
     <span>{{personalDetail.fname}}</span>
  </td>   
  <td>
     <span>{{personalDetail.lname}}</span>
  </td> 
   <td>
     <span>{{personalDetail.email}}</span>
  </td> 
           
          <td>
             <select  ng-init="personalDetail.selectedDpn= personalDetail.checkxDrpn[1]" ng-options="value as value.selectVal for value in personalDetail.checkxDrpn track by value.key"
        ng-model="personalDetail.selectedDpn" ></select>
       </td>
    <td>
  <textarea ng-model="personalDetail.indivalCmts" ng-disabled="personalDetail.selected">
    
  </textarea>
    </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
 
</body>
</html>
```